# I'm trying to implement 'multi-threading' to do both training and prediction(testing) at the same time

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, neural-network, gpu

I'm trying to implement 'multi-threading' to do both training and prediction(testing) at the same time. And I'm gonna use the python module 'threading' as  shown in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/FIFOQueue
And the followings are questions.

1. If I use the python module 'threading', does tensorflow use more portion of gpu or more portion of cpu?
2. Do I have to make two graphs(neural nets which have the same topology) in tensorflow one for prediction and the other for training? Or is it okay to make just one graph?

I'll be very grateful to anyone who can answer these questions! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you use python `threading` module, it will only make use of `cpu`; also python threading not for run time parallelism, you should use `multiprocessing`.
2. In your model if you are using `dropout` or `batch_norm` like ops which change based on `training` and `validation`, it's a good idea to create separate graphs, reusing (validation graph will reuse all training variables) the common variable for validation/testing.

Note: you can use one graph also, with additional operations which changes behaviors based on training/validation.

Comment: Thanks! Mrinal . So you mean that I can encourage my computer to use more portion of gpu  if I use multi-processing? And one more, what does 'run time parallelism' exactly mean?

Comment: no, actually I meant, since `threading` doesn';t support run-time parallelism you can use `multiprocessing` for the same. both will use `cpu` only. If your input pipeline is efficient tensorflow will make use of gpu efficiently (`gpu` will get data from `cpu` and wont run out of data for computation).

Comment: Thanks a lot! your advice will really help me!